# How to trigger laravel jobs failed() method when job fails?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Currently I'm calling task `Report.php` and generating report using `generateReport()` method. I have checked that the jobs have been executed using CLI command `php artsan queue:listen`. If anything goes wrong while calling `Artisan::call()` the error message will be displayed in terminal. So I want to catch the exception in `failed()` and I want to log the error into logs. 
I have tried with `try catch` in `handle()` method but it's not catching the exception.

```
protected $options;
public function __construct($options)
{
    $this->options = array_merge(
        [
            'task'  => 'Report',
            'do'    => 'generateReport',
            'limit' => '10000'
        ],
        $options
    );

}
public function handle()
{
    Artisan::call('execute', [
        '--task'        => $this->options['task'],
        '--do'          => $this->options['do'],
        '--parameters'  => $this->options,

    ]);

}

public function failed()
{
    //
}
```

How can I trigger the `failed()` and get the error into logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Artisan::call` is actually just calling the `execute` console class so if you throw an `Exception` in there it should automatically end up in the `failed` method.

However, in `5.2` the `Exception` object is not passed to the failed method (this was added in `5.3`).

**Laravel 5.2**

So if you need the `Exception` object passed to the `failed` method then you will need to do something like this in `5.2`:

```
public function handle()
{
    try {
      Artisan::call('execute', [
        '--task'        => $this->options['task'],
        '--do'          => $this->options['do'],
        '--parameters'  => $this->options,            
      ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      $this->failed($e)
    }
}

public function failed(\Exception $e = null)
{
    //handle error
}
```

**Laravel 5.3+**

In `5.3` the `Exception` is automatically passed to `failed` so your code would be like this:

```
public function handle()
{
    Artisan::call('execute', [
      '--task'        => $this->options['task'],
      '--do'          => $this->options['do'],
      '--parameters'  => $this->options,            
    ]);
}

public function failed(\Exception $e = null)
{
    //handle error
}
```

Comment: what if i want to continue job queue when it throw an exception? because  when it throw an exception it stop processing all queue work. and i need to run Artisan queue:work command manually.

Comment: This answer is wrong at all, `failed()` method is the way to do some actions after job fail, for example - write a log, or send mail to administrator with information about failed job, this method beign called if any exception throwed in `handle()` and could not be called directly.

Comment: @OlegShakhov I am not sure you read the answer completely. There is nothing to stop you calling the `failled` method directly since it is a public method. In Laravel 5.2 and before the exception is not passed to the `failed` method. In Laravel 5.3 and after the exception is always passed to the `failed` method and my answer clearly explains this.